# C# Cast an Array Interfaced Reference before sending

Tags: c#, interface, casting, ref

I have this code

```
public MyResponse innerFunc(ref MyElem[]);
public IResponse myFunc(ref IElem[] myElem)
{
     return this.innerFunc(ref (A_CAST_OR_SOMETHING) myElem);
}
```

Where

- MyResponse:IResponse
- MyElem:IElem
- A_CAST_OR_SOMETHING should be of MyElem[]

When I do this

```
public IResponse myFunc(ref IElem[] myElem)
{
     return this.innerFunc(ref ((MyElem[]) myElem));
}
```

The compiler higlights **the brackets** (only the brackets)and say:

> *A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable*

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 2):

The way that `ref` and `out` work, the thing you pass in as that parameter must be able to be assigned to directly. In short, it must be able to appear to the left of an `=` sign. Since you cannot do this:

```
((MyElem[])myElem) = foo;
```

then you also cannot do this:

```
foo((MyElem[])myElem);
```

To fix this you need to introduce a temporary variable:

```
public IResponse myFunc(ref IElem[] myElem)
{
    var temp = (MyElem[])myElem;
    var response = this.innerFunc(ref temp);

    myElem = (IElem[])temp;
    return response;
}
```

Comment: `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'IElem[]' to type 'MyElem[]'.
   at MyClass.myFunc(ref IElem[] myElem)`

Comment: Is `MyElem` a struct type or a class type? I was sure you could cast arrays of classes in both directions...

Comment: it's a Class. I thought so too.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast `ref` parameters. The type of the parameter must match exactly. Thus no casting operators are possible in this position. You could create a matching variable before calling `innerFunc`:

```
public IResponse myFunc(ref IElem[] myElem)
{
    MyElem[] p = (MyElem[])myElem;
    var result = this.innerFunc(ref p);
    myElem = p;
    return result;
}
```

This works if the actual type of the parameter is a `MyElem[]`. If it's just an `IElem[]`, you'll need to create a separate array.

Comment: `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'IElem[]' to type 'MyElem[]'.
   at MyClass.myFunc(ref IElem[] myElem)`

Comment: @Michael, Botz, Could it be that I'm forced to cast 1 by 1 every item on the array?

Comment: @apacay If you pass in an actual IElem [] then yes. You would need to create a copy of the array with a different type, in both directions. But then again maybe you should rethink your design. Why do you need to pass a ref Parameter? Without ref, you also pass a reference to the same object, you only need ref if you actually want to change the object that reference is pointing to.

Comment: Because the Response is "taken" and I use myElems changes outside that class. You mean I should do `myFunc(IElem[] myElem, out IElem exitElem)`?

Comment: @apacay Why don't you just use an `IList<IElem>`? You could add and remove elements and it would modify the original list you passed in. And you can add new `MyElem` objects to a `List<IElem>` without casting. It looks like you use a ref parameter to be able to resize the original array, but then an array is maybe the wrong data type.

Comment: The ref is required by a (web)service made in another language (so SOAP "translator" is there) Each item of `MyElem[]` is edited in some incomplete fields. With that data the upper class has to do some stuff.

Comment: @apacay If you really require the ref parameter, i guess you will have to copy the array. ref parameters need an exact type match after all, and you also need a more specific type (`myFunc(IElem)->innerFunc(MyElem)`). If the types were the other way around (`myFunc(MyElem)->innerFunc(IElem)`), you would probably be able to just cast a `MyElem[]` to an `IElem[]` and store that in another variable, which should work.